# Extend the scrollable content of gnu-screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

Using the `screen` terminal environment, I ofen enter copy mode by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. However, the scrollable output is often too short for me to view the desired information.

What do I modify to extend the length of this output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's all there on the screen man page:

You can do it from the command line when you start screen:

> -h num
>
> ```
>     Specifies the history scrollback buffer to be num lines high.
> ```

Or from the .screenrc file:

> defscrollback num
>
> Same as the scrollback command except that the default setting for
>   new windows is changed. Initial setting is 100.

Or from within screen, using the <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> command:

> scrollback num
>
> Set the size of the scrollback buffer for the current windows to
>   num lines. The default scrollback is 100 lines.  See also the
>   "defscrollback" command and use "C-a i" to view  the  current
>   setting.